# List iterations and regex, what is the better way to remove the text I don' t need?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

We handle data from volunteers, that data is entered in to a form using ODK.  When the data is downloaded the header (column names) row contains a lot of 'stuff' we don' t need.  The pattern is as follows:

'Group1/most_common/G27'

I want to replace the column names (there can be up to 200) or create a copy of the DataFrame with column names that just contain the G-code (Gxxx).  I think I got it.

What is the faster or better way to do this?
IS the output reliable in terms of sort order?  As of now it appears that the results list is in the same order as the original list.

```
    y = ['Group1/most common/G95', 'Group1/most common/G24', 'Group3/plastics/G132']

    import re
    r = []
    for x in y:
        m = re.findall(r'G\d+', x)
        r.append(m)

    # the comprehension below is to flatten it
    # append.m gives me a list of lists (each list has one item)

    results = [q for t in r for q in t]
    print(results)

    ['G95', 'G24', 'G132']
```

The idea would be to iterate through the column names in the DataFrame (or a copy), delete what I don't need and replace (inplace=True).

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Group1/most common/G95', 
                           'Group1/most common/G24', 
                           'Group3/plastics/G132'])
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Group1/most common/G95, Group1/most common/G24, Group3/plastics/G132]
Index: []

df.columns = df.columns.str.extract('(G\d+)', expand=False)
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [G95, G24, G132]
Index: []
```

Another solution with [`rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) and select last values with `[-1]`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit('/').str[-1]
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [G95, G24, G132]
Index: []
```

Comment: thanks, the str.extract method looks like the more straight forward way.

Comment: Glad can help, yes it is nice solution. Nice weekend!